# Python 2.7 How to add images on the canvas with Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, canvas, tkinter

I need to add an image to the canvas. I have tried countless amounts of things, and finally decided to make a question on here.

This is what I have imported

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

And this is the line of code I'm trying to add to import an image from the same folder the main file is in.

```
c.create_image(100,100, anchor=N, image = ghost.jpg)
```

I've also tried putting `""`s around `'ghost.jpg'` and it says *the Image does not exist* then. Without the quotes it says *"global name 'ghost' does not exist."*

Can anyone help?

Comment: here's [`slideshow.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c) script that implements showing a slideshow for images in a given directory using `tkinter`.

Comment: You do need to put the file name in quotation marks (ie use `"ghost.jpg"`). Is there an image named `ghost.jpg` in the same directory as your python script?

Comment: So how can I add jpeg/png images to the canvas? Seems like everyone that tries this has the image pop up off the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Canvas.create_image](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method)'s image argument

> should be a [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) or [BitmapImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/bitmapimage.htm), or a
>   compatible object (such as the [PIL's PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagetk.htm)). The application must
>   keep a reference to the image object.

Answer (score 1):

```
from Tkinter import * 
"""python 2.7 =Tkinter"""
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
app = Tk()
temp=Image.open("photo.jpg")
temp = temp.save("photo.ppm","ppm")
photo = PhotoImage(file = "photo.ppm")
imagepanel=Label(app,image = photo)
imagepanel.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

This is a bit of code I wrote in python 2.7 with Tkinter and PIL to import a jpg file from a given directory, this doesn't pop up off the screen.
You should replace photo with the file name (and directory) and app with the relevant variable you set.